# Increase and decrease a variable until a number is reached in java

Tags: java

I have this class:

```
public class Vehicle {
    private float speed;

     public void Acceleration()
     {
         ++speed;
     }  
}
```

Each time `Acceleration` method have been called `speed` variable increase by one.

I need to change `Acceleration` method this way that, if `speed` variable reached to value 10 and `Acceleration` method have been called the speed value doesn't have to be changed.

In this tutorial I can't use if else or any other conditional operators(I think I  have to manipulate with modulo and divide operations).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the purpose of avoiding `if`?

Comment: @UnholySheep Probably a crappy exercise to show integer/floating point operator quirkiness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a silly question, but just using the divide operator one can go with something like

```
public void Acceleration()
{
    speed += (1 - (int) (speed / 10));
}
```

The expression `(int) (speed / 10)` is equal to zero until speed reaches 10, when it becomes 1.

Comment: `speed` is declared as a `float`, so `speed/10` will not be zero (unless `speed` is zero).

Comment: `speed += (1 - (int) (speed / 10))`

Comment: What if speed is byte type?

Comment: @UnholySheep, oops, I just assumed it was an int. I edit with 493msi's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `Math.min()` to limit the max value:

```
 speed = Math.min(speed+1, 10);
```

This may use if/else or ?: internally though.